# HTML string returning different values when logged vs. when appended to element

Tags: javascript, html, string, string-concatenation

I am trying to dynamically generate strings containing HTML then appending them to the document. When I `console.log` the string the value shows up exactly how I expect it to. But when I append it to the HTML document, it somehow changes.

```
for (var i=0; i < roster.length; i++) {
            if (roster[i].attended === 1) {
                var attendedSVG = 'user-check.svg';
            }
            else {
                var attendedSVG = 'user-x.svg';
            }
            var _fkUserID = roster[i]._fkUserID;
            var firstName = roster[i].firstName;
            var lastName = roster[i].lastName;
            var cancelJSFunction = "cancelRequest('"+_fkUserID+"', '"+firstName+"', '"+lastName+"', '"+day+"', '"+time+"');";

            console.log(cancelJSFunction);

/* Returns: "cancelRequest('userID', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'day', 'time')" */

            var html = "<div class='user'><img class='cx' src='x-square.svg' onClick='"+cancelJSFunction+"'></img>"+firstName+' '+lastName+"<img class='attended' src='"+attendedSVG+"'></img></div>";
            $("#roster-container").append(html);

/* Appends:
<img class="cx" src="x-square.svg" onclick="cancelRequest(" userID',="" 'firstName',="" 'lastName',="" 'day',="" 'time')'="">
 */

}
```

How come what gets logged and what gets appended are two completely different strings with all the ="" added in there?

Comment: How 'console.log(cancelJSFunction);'  return  "adminCancelRequest('userID', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'day', 'time')" when you assign it to "cancelRequest('..."?

Comment: Not sure if this is related but you are using single quotes in your HTML AND your javascript function which is going to cause issues. You should never add event handlers like this. You are using jQuery. Let it help you. Instead of hard coding the onclick give your element some data attributes or something and bind the click event

Comment: @zhulien I made some naming changes to make the code easier to read but forgot to change that one. Fixed it in the post.

Comment: @Marie that seems like a good alternative to this method, I will do that instead. I use double quotes to start and finish a string, and single quotes to add strings inside, which has usually worked for me in the past. I find just find it odd that all these ="" get added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rendered HTML looks like this

```
<div class='user'>
    <img class='cx' src='x-square.svg' onClick='cancelRequest('userID', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'day', 'time')'></img> 
    Jane Doe 
    <img class='attended' src='xxxx'></img>
</div>
```

Your onClick only contains `cancelRequest(` and the rest is  broken. This is the danger of using the event attributes. You should always bind your events to avoid issues like this (and allow you to bind multiple events). It looks like you are using jQuery so you can use it to make event binding dead simple. For example

```js
function cancelRequest(_fkUserID, firstName, lastName, day, time) {
  console.log("Canceling: ", _fkUserID, firstName, lastName, day, time);
}

var _fkUserID = 1, firstName = "Jane", lastName = "Doe", day = 2, time = 3;
  
var cancelJSFunction = function () { 
    cancelRequest(_fkUserID, firstName, lastName, day, time); 
};

var newElements = $("<div class='user'><img class='cx' src='x-square.svg'></img>"+firstName+' '+lastName+"<img class='attended' src='attendedSVG'></img></div>");

$("#roster-container").append(newElements);

newElements.find(".cx").click(cancelJSFunction);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="roster-container"></div>
```